Why do we add this constant (representing the solution to Laplace's equation) to our Green's function?
For Poisson's equation on a circular domain:
$$\Delta u(r,\theta) = Q(r,\theta) \\ u(a,\theta) = h(\theta)$$
We want a Green's function to solve the inhomogeneous problem subject to homogeneous boundary conditions:
$$\Delta G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \delta(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0) \\ G(a,\theta,r_0,\theta_0) = 0 \\ G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|$$
Where we note that this definition of $G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0)$, does NOT satisfy the homogeneous boundary condition, and we instead have to introduce negative image source and we redefine our Green's function to instead be:
$$\tag{1}G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0| + v(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0)$$ which now satisfies the existence of the negative image at some new location $\textbf{x}_0*$:
$$\tag{2} \Delta G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \delta(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) + ^-\delta(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0*)$$

What I don't understand is how we define $v$ in (2). According to Habermann's Applied Partial Differential Equations Fifth Edition, we define $v$ as the sum of both the Green's function for the negative image and the constant homogeneous solution of Laplace's equation, c:
$$\tag{3} G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0*| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0| + c$$ (pg 423).
I don't understand why we couldn't just define it as:
$$\tag{4} G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0*|$$
and then plug this into Poisson's formula $\int\int G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0)Q(\textbf{x}_0)d\textbf{x}_0 + \oint \nabla_{\textbf{x}_0}G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0)h(\theta)\cdot d\textbf{S}_0$ to get the full solution. We don't have add on this term for say a semi-infinite slab $\Delta u(x,y>0) = Q(x,y>0)$ (p. 420-421); for a semi-infinite slab our Green's function would instead just be (4), I don't understand why it's different here.

EDIT: Here are the pages which I'm referencing:
p. 423:

p. 420-421



"According to Habermann." The reference is missing.

@Gonçalo Just added the book and page numbers. I also added the pages I'm referencing themselves for convenience. Eqns (9.5.53) and (9.5.44) are the equations I'm noting as being different.

@Gonçalo Hopefully that helped!

You need the constant $c$ (which is in fact a function of $r_0$ and $a$) in order that $G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x_0})$ vanishes on the circle $|\mathbf{x}|=a$. This is explained after Eq. (9.5.53).

@Gonçalo Ah! That makes sense! Thank you for pointing that out! Sometimes this stuff goes right over my head. So I'm guessing then that (9.5.45) would technically have it's own c, but it doesn't show itself because no modification was necessary to make $G(x,y=0,x_0,y_0) = 0$ beyond simply adding on a Green's function for the image source term at $\textbf{x}_0*$. If say we wanted $G$ to be 0 at instead $y=1$, we would have to include a term $c$ in (9.5.45) to further modify $G$ to force it to become 0 at $y=1$ just like we did for a term at $|\textbf{x}| =a$ for (9.5.53).
